# How to get XPath value from nested div

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I get the value 5000+ by providing key "Installs" to xpath.

```
      <div class="hAyfc">
        <div class="BgcNfc">Installs</div>
        <span class="htlgb">
          <div><span class="htlgb">5,000+</span></div>
        </span>
      </div>
```

I tried this response.xpath('//span/div/span/text()').extract() but it's giving all text.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"...giving all text"*? What is your desired and current output? Also try `//div[.="Installs"]/following-sibling::span/div/span/text()`

Comment: @Andersson it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
response.xpath('//div[./div/text()="Installs"]/span/div/span/text()').extract_first()
```

It searches for a `div` with a `div` child that has the `text()="Installs"`, then searches for the `span` containing the value you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response.xpath('./div/span[@class="htlgb"]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: i don't want to use the class as it may change.

Comment: sure okay, can you give me the website, i'll update my answer accordingly.